# In github, is it possible to compare between a branch and a tag?

Tags: github

In **github** interface, how is it possible (if possible at all) to compare between a **branch** and a **tag**?

It is fairly ubiquitous to compare two branches, or compare two tags, but how to compare a tag and a branch?

For example, if there are release tags, and there is a master branch (from which releases are cut), is it possible to check what was pushed to master since the last release?

P.S. My question is about github GUI interface, not git command line interface.

Answer (score 1):

Using the tag name should work: [example](https://github.com/octocat/linguist/compare/v4.8.6...master)

```
https://github.com/octocat/linguist/compare/v4.8.6...master
```

It does compare between a tag and `master`.

[image: GitHub GUI]